# How to trigger a single MDL snackbar event when either one of many similar buttons are clicked

Tags: javascript, material-design-lite

### I'm using the snackbar from [Google's Material Design Lite](https://getmdl.io/components/index.html#snackbar-section)

I'm not very proficient with javascript so I'll explain the scenario - say if there are five buttons and when either one is pressed, I would like the snackbar to show a common message. How do I go about implementing this?

While the code below has only *one button* that triggers the snackbar event, can I have multiple buttons to trigger the same snackbar when clicked?

```
<button id="demo-show-toast" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised" type="button">Show Toast</button>
<div id="demo-toast-example" class="mdl-js-snackbar mdl-snackbar">
  <div class="mdl-snackbar__text"></div>
  <button class="mdl-snackbar__action" type="button"></button>
</div>
<script>
(function() {
  'use strict';
  var snackbarContainer = document.querySelector('#demo-toast-example');
  var showToastButton = document.querySelector('#demo-show-toast');
  showToastButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    'use strict';
    var data = {message: 'Common Message '};
    snackbarContainer.MaterialSnackbar.showSnackbar(data);
  });
}());
</script>
```

**Example use case:** In a forum, when the user clicks on either the upvote or the downvote buttons of a comment (Assuming there are alot of comments and therefore alot of buttons), the snackbar shows the common message "Please log in to vote".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just define a 'throw snackbar' function and pass it to the listener for all of the buttons you want to use it.

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    var snackbarContainer = document.querySelector('#demo-toast-example');
    var showToastButton1 = document.querySelector('#demo-show-toast1');
    var showToastButton2 = document.querySelector('#demo-show-toast2');

    function loggedOutSnackbar () {
      var data = {message: 'Common Message'};
      snackbarContainer.MaterialSnackbar.showSnackbar(data);
    }

    showToastButton1.addEventListener('click', loggedOutSnackbar);
    showToastButton2.addEventListener('click', loggedOutSnackbar);
})();
```

<strike>I'm pretty sure you don't need to wrap it all in a function, either. This should work in your script tags or in a separate js file you could call in your html.</strike>

I've been corrected! The immediately invoked function is important to avoid polluting the global namespace. You can just add that part back in. I'm not used to putting JS in the HTML. :D